# Pagination with will-paginate using the RSpotify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm playing arround with the RSpotify Gem https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify
Now I tried to add pagination using the will-paginate gem. As you can see on my site here https://rubyjukebox.herokuapp.com/ after you search for an artist and there are more than 8 the pagination works fine.

In my artists_controller.rb I have the following code:

```
def index
if !params[:artist_name].empty?
@artists = RSpotify::Artist.search(params[:artist_name]).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :per_page => 8)
else
redirect_to root_path
end
end
```

And in index.html.erb I have:

```
<%= will_paginate @artist, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

This seem to work just fine. But when you choose an Artist and you are redirected to the album list, the pagination is shown but it shows every available album on every site instead of only showing 5 albums on each site.

Again in my artists_controller.rb I have:

```
def show
@artist = RSpotify::Artist.find(params[:id])
@album = @artist.albums(country: 'DE').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end
```

And in my show.html.erb I have:

```
<%= will_paginate @album, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Any ideas where my mistake is?

Comment: Please show the code that generates the album list. Looks like you do not iterate over @album correctly.

Comment: Thank you, that was enough as a hint. I had `<% @artist.albums(country: 'DE').each do |album| %>` before but that is exactly what I defined in @albums. So the working code looks like this:

`<% @album.each do |album| %>`

Answer (score 0):

Paginate is a class method and will not work with instance variable.
Try Artist.album.paginate

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation, so you should work on that. Cheers.